# Show facebook like count on android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to android and i have to implement some code to show count of facebook like on android app.please guys help me out.im totally confused.please guys help me out...

Comment: what is count ? can you please explain more

Comment: @sarvan Kumar,,number of likes

Comment: try library from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118 it completely solve this issue - show like button with count of likes, allows to login and like any url.

Answer (score 1):

If you Facebook Fan page is http://www.facebook.com/IronMan3TheMovie, you can check the Like count using the Graph API, e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/IronMan3TheMovie. Notice the part where it says: `"likes": 62968,`.

Parse the JSON returned by the above call (changes are needed to check your Page) and then display the count.

You can query the graph in the following form:

`http://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}`

OR

`http://graph.facebook.com/{page_user_name}`

Answer (score 0):

Keep one Button and when user clicks that button send 1 to server and add to previous count no....

Code:

```
HttpClient c= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(YOUR_SERVER_URL?cnt=1);//send cnt value as Request parameter
HttpRespone response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
//Read the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
//Server side create JSP page.catch count value as 
request.getparameter("cnt");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.but i really meant is,, i got a android app and it shows how many likes on a specific fb fam page..Can you please give me some help...

Comment: If more than one users are using app and if u want to display how many like it then there should be client server communication required...