# How to add to my android application a button than do like to a facebook page?

Tags: android, facebook, button, facebook-like

I've tried this: https://github.com/crowjdh/android-facebook-like-button-integration

but it not work.
I search something more simple than do "like" to my facebook page when user press a button to android application I'm developing.
thank you

Comment: read this post, there is complete solution: http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html

Comment: It is outdated solution

Answer (score 7):

Use this library: [Facebook Like button for Android](http://blog.shamanland.com/p/facebook-like-button.html).
There is [detailed manual here](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html).

Sources: https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button

Gradle dependency:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.8'
}
```

The simplest way to add like button:

```
<com.shamanland.facebook.likebutton.FacebookLikeButton
    style="@style/Widget.FacebookLikeButton"
    app:pageUrl="http://blog.shamanland.com/"
    app:pageTitle="Developer's notes"
    app:pageText="This is blog about Android development."
    app:pagePicture="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
```

This view will be drawn in your layout: [image]

In additional there is box with count of likes.

[image]

Comment: How does this react on click? Is it dependant on previous Facebook login, or does it somehow open in browser or similar? What if user isn't logged in on Facebook (or have it)?

Comment: It will open dialog with `WebView`. This web-view will keep user session.

Comment: I have "Namespace 'app' is not bound' error on XML.

Comment: You have to add this line to the first tag in your layout: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a webview and put your button inside.

You can try something like this :

```
 String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=80&height=50&action=like&colorscheme=light&href=http://beta.demo.dy/web/service/304.htm";
             //   webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
             class LikeWebviewClient  extends WebViewClient
                {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: thanks akram!! but when I press the like button visualized in webview do not happen nothing

Comment: I think the user must be logged in his Fb account to like the page.